# How to draw all paths from (0, 0) to (n, n) by moving (0, +1) or (+1, 0) in Sage?

Tags: performance, optimization, graphics, sage

I've been trying do the same as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112395/how-to-draw-all-paths-from-1-1-to-n-n-by-move-1-0-or-0-1) just for fun, **but in Sage**. I was impressed about how short is the code in Mathematica to generate that illustration(and I can also notice how ugly is Mathematica's language). I think it's a good way to practice Sage, though.

This is what I've done:

```
n=3
A=sum(line([(j, i), (n, i)]) for j in range(n+1) for i in range(n+1))
B=sum(line([(i, j), (i, n)]) for j in range(n+1) for i in range(n+1))
G=Graphics()
G+=A+B
G.show(figsize=[4, 4], axes=False)
result = []
min = int('1'*n, 2)
max = int('1'*n+'0'*n, 2)
combinations = [bin(i)[2:] for i in range(min, max+1)]
for num in combinations:
    valid = ''.join(['0']*(2*n-len(num))) + num
    zeros = valid.count('0')
    ones = valid.count('1')
    if zeros == n and ones == n:
        result.append(valid)
#At this point all the paths are stored in the variable 'results' in binary form.
#For example '010101' means right, left, right, left, right, left
paths = []
for element in result:
    path = [(0, 0)]
    for index, direction in enumerate(list(element)):
        if direction == '0':
            path.append((path[index][0]+1, path[index][1]))
        else:
            path.append((path[index][0], path[index][1]+1))
    paths.append(path)
C=sum(line(p, alpha=0.3, hue=(color/float(len(paths)))) for color, p in enumerate(paths))
T=Graphics()
T+=C
T.show(figsize=[4, 4], axes=False)
```

In my resulting image all paths get overlapped. In the mentioned question the paths can be viewed clearly. I don't know how they do it and it would be interesting to see it in Sage.

How would you do it so the code is shorter(but follows good practices) and the paths doesn't get overlapped??

Comment: They avoid overlapping by adding the offset `1/(2 Sqrt[2]) {-1 + (2 (-1 + i))/(-1 + m), 1 - (2 (-1 + i))/(-1 + m)}` to each path. The index `i` corresponds to your `p` in the enumeration of paths. For this to work well, one has to sort the paths appropriately (lexicographic sort of binary strings).

Comment: Thanks, @Meta. and what is `m` in that offset?

Comment: It says `m = Length@paths` in the Mathematica source, and I trust you know how to express that in Python...